# Groups of order 30

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

> **Dummit&Foote p.143** Let $G$ be a group of order 30. Let $P \in Syl_5(G)$ and let $Q \in Syl_3(G)$. If either $P$ or $Q$ is normal in
>   $G$, then both $P$ and $Q$ are characteristic subgroups of $PQ$. .....

I don't understand the above parts, stuck on it for hours. How can it be derived?

Comment: @DylanMoreland: Yes, I know the fact. So if $P$ is normal, then $P$ is characteristic in $PQ$. But how can I show both?

Comment: Beaten to it. Hope it makes sense now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since either $P,Q$ is normal you know that $PQ\leqslant G$. But, since $|P\cap Q|=1$ (necessarily since $|P\cap Q|\mid \text{gcd}(|P|,|Q|)=1$) one has that $\displaystyle |PQ|=\frac{|P||Q|}{|P\cap Q|}=\frac{5\cdot 3}{1}=15$. Thus, $PQ$ is a group of order $15$. Now, it's easy to check that since $5\not\equiv1\text{ mod }3$ that $P,Q$ are normal in $PQ$. But, it's a common fact that normal Sylow subgroups are characteristic.

*Remark:* In fact, all groups of order $15$ are cyclic.

Comment: It seems like $PQ$ has to be cyclic as well, but that's not needed here.

Comment: Right, because all abelian groups of squarefree order are necessarily cyclic.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear to all that $ G $ contain a normal subgroup of order 15.Say H.now we show $ H $is the only subgroup of order 15 in$ G $ . (Let K be another subgroup of of order 
K.then |$ H\cap K$|=$\frac {|H||K|} {|HK|}$> =8.whcih imply $H\cap K=H=K$.).T
This condition followas that $H$ remains invariant under any isomorphisom of $ G $ to $ G $.